# How to generate datetime in behave-html-pretty-formatter test report filename?

Tags: python, automated-tests, report, bdd, playwright

I've written in Python Playwright and Behave test automation framework. For test reports I use behave-html-pretty-formatter. When I type `behave -f html-pretty -o ./reports/behave-report.html` report generates successfully, but after executing report filename is just `behave-report.html`. I want to have a datetime in a report filename. How can I achieve this? Unfortunately, in the documentation I cannot find this information.